# Trying to group categorical variables with similar prefixes

Tags: r

I believe my problem is quite simple. I would like to be able to group categorical variables I have in my data frame to a larger unit. for example

```
lifestyle.travel.europe                                  
lifestyle.travel.long-haul                               
lifestyle.travel.ireland                                 
lifestyle.fashion
```

I want to be able to group into maybe just lifestyle, or perhaps lifestyle.travel. Thanks for the help!

Edit: sorry, I forgot to add that I would like to sum these into their counts, so if there is 1 observation for those 4 listed above, then I would like my final output to have

```
category     n 
lifestyle    4
```

Comment: Perhaps do `sub("\\..*", "", df1$column)`

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(df1$Column, 1, sep=".")
```

---

Or another option is to remove the characters starting from the first `.`

```
sub("\\..*", "", df1$column)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` function to extract the desired sub-string. For examples,

```
cat <- substr(iris$Species, 1, 2)
```

You may want to convert the outcome to factor as well.

```
cat <- as.factor(cat)
levels(cat)
# "se" "ve" "vi"
```

You can get the size of each category as below;

```
table(cat)  
# cat
# se ve vi 
# 50 50 50
```